# how to detect if your finger is contacted with a masked sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skphysicsbody

i need to say that one developer told that you should create an skphysics body so that the function body at point works so if there is any specific code to create an skphysics body of that sprite ? because i already have given an alpha mask in sks file in the physics part. by the way he also gave me an example of code which is :

```
if let _ = physicsworld.body(at : fingerlocation)
```

but you know when i use this code in my `touchesmoved` function it dose not work for only the masked portion of that sprite it works for the whole bounding rectangle of that sprite

Comment: You can create a `CGPath` representation of your sprite and test for touches with its `contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to limit the physics body to just the texture of the sprite instead of a rectangle.

```
 let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "imageNameHere")
    maskedSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture , size: texture.size)
```

If you're just trying to see if its made contact, you don't need a physics body at all, you can add a name to the node and in touchesBegan check the node at the point touched to see if it has the same name as the masked sprite.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        switch atPoint(location).name {
            case "maskedsprite"?: print("masked sprite touched")
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but this didn't work only on the masked part it works for the rectancle

Comment: :/ sorry about that

Comment: sorry that it didn't work. I thought I understood what you were asking but I was wrong.